# How to fix google crawl on dynamically generated content on webpage

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-crawlers

I am getting content from the sql table when the user scroll through ajax . I need to know whether google crawler crawl at the dynamically generated ajax content on the webpage this is the script i am using to get the content from the sql table on scroll jquery function

```
 jQuery.ajax({    
        url:ajaxurl,
        type:"POST",
        data:{
            page:page,
            action:"my_loadmore"
        },
        error:function(response){
          console.log("error");  
        },
        success:function(data){
          if (data !== undefined ){ 
               jQuery('button.myLoad').data('page',(page+1));
               jQuery('#left-area').append(data);
           }
           else {
               jQuery('button.myLoad').remove();
           } 
        }
    });
```

Comment: If you use some special packages like react you may need to read baout Server Side Rendering (SSR). Elsewhere you have to generate a direct link for very page besides of your current code e.g. when a user calls ajaxurl.php?page=2 you shoud fully render the page 2 and open a new way in your wesbite to access those pages via the hyperlinks.

Comment: how i would make it in jQuery?

Comment: The "direct hyperlink" suggestion has nothing to do with Jquery. For example you may put a direct link to `url.php?page=2` beside of the "Load more button". So the serach engine can crawl to page 2 through that hyperlink not by clicking on the load more button.

Comment: @AliSheikhpour I am using onscroll jquery function to load new content